# Is there another version of the binutils for x86_64?

Tags: binutils

I am trying to install a cross-compiler following instructions that I found [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler). I am using the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 13.10. As soon as I entered the command to configure the binutils I get:

```
Configuring for a x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu host. 
Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized 
Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized 
Unrecognized host system name x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.
```

Is there really a 64-bit version of the binutils? If not, can anyone tell me what commands to enter to avoid this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a little googleing I found a post. In this post the author explains that all you have to do in order to install the binutils on a 64-bit linux system is fool the system by typing "linux32" before your command. For example in this case it would be:

```
linux32 ./configure
linux32 make
linux32 make install
```

to build for a regular compiler and this:

```
linux32 ./configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls
linux32 make
linux32 make install
```

to build for a cross-compiler.

Comment: Perfect! Thans you so much!

Comment: Also, it's i686-pc-linux-gnu on my machine

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error with binutils-2.9.I just used binutils-2.28(a lower version) and it worked for me.

Comment: This was my solution